# Using an instance method in scope returns incorrect result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, ruby-on-rails-5, instance-methods

user.rb

```
has_many :users_positions
has_many :positions, through: :users_positions
//users table has position_id as a field, it represents the current position user is associated with

scope :under_25_value, -> { joins(:positions).where('(value * positions.available / 100) in (?)', 0..24) }
scope :under_50_value, -> { joins(:positions).where('(value * positions.available / 100) in (?)', 25..49) }
scope :over_50_value, -> { joins(:positions).where('(value * positions.available / 100) >= ?', 50) }

def current_positions
  value * position.available / 100
end
```

In the rails console, if I try the below command it returns users who have current_positions as 75 but it should have returned under 25.

```
User.under_25_value
```

Please help me find where I am going wrong

Sample Data

```
User id: 894, name: "Jack", value: 18, position_id: 3
Position id: 3, available: 100, name: 'Manager'
```

Comment: what are the `value` and `positions.available` fields contains?

Comment: @Vishal value is the field in users tables and positions is another table and available is the field in the table. value and available are both integer data types. Users table has position_id as a field, it represents the position user is associated with. I have added sample data in the question section. Please check

Comment: Can you please add the record which has value of 75 and it is come under `under_25_value` scope.  I am still confuse about the calculation you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your user model already has a `position_id` column that points to the positions you want to query for each user, you can define a `position` association and update your code like below:

## user.rb

```
has_many :users_positions
has_many :positions, through: :users_positions
//users table has position_id as a field, it represents the current position user is associated with
has_one :position

scope :under_25_value, -> { joins(:position).where('(value * positions.available / 100) in (?)', 0..24) }
scope :under_50_value, -> { joins(:position).where('(value * positions.available / 100) in (?)', 25..49) }
scope :over_50_value, -> { joins(:position).where('(value * positions.available / 100) >= ?', 50) }

def current_positions
  value * position.available / 100
end
```

Comment: Each user can have multiple positions, position_id keys on changing according to the scenario in our code base. So under users_positions we keep a track of all the positions a user had. Under instance method current_positions position.available, position here is the current position id in the user record, and available is the field corresponding to the position.